# Discharging a battery completely

Tags: batteries

EE newbie here. If I'm discharging a battery by connecting it in series to a 1 ohm resistor, should the voltage across the terminals of the battery be 0 when the battery is fully discharged? I know that when a battery is in a device like a remote it doesn't reach 0 volts by the time it's dead (though I'm not sure why), but there's nothing I know of stopping a battery from completely dissipating all energy inside of it when simply connected to a resistor which would leave the potential across the terminals of the battery at 0.

Comment: 0V is a "dead short". Most batteries should be run with a safety mechanism to prevent reaching 0V.  These are commonly built in to most lithium battery packs.  Some of the old nickel cadmium chargers would require a minimum voltage to begin recharging.  What kind of battery is it?  How dead do you want your battery? Brick dead or ???

Comment: It is an Energizer MAX AA alkaline battery. I'm just being curious, so when the batteries in my TV remote are "dead", there is still charge contained within those batteries and they've just reached such a low voltage that they cannot operate the remote? I read somewhere on this forum that most battery operated electronics contain safety mechanisms that ensure their batteries do not reach too low of a voltage since going to 0 volts is irreversible, and I wondered if a resistor could effectively take a battery all the way to 0.

Comment: @vuuuuuuuman123 You are now likely mixing non-rechargeable alkaline primary cells and rechargeable lithium ion cells. Lithium ion cells damage if voltage drops too low so you must protect from that happening, so they don't burst into fire or explode the next time you charge them. Alkalines don't care. And when your remote stops working, you change new batteries. There is no need to fully discharge used AA batteries before recycling them.